# RequireJS error on IE : dependency file name is the ID instead of the file name

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, requirejs

I'm getting a strange behavior with RequireJS on IE.
Sometimes (this is purely random) the generated js file reference appears with the ID, not the file name.

I explain,

on the paths I have:

```
jqGridz: "jquery.jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min"
```

on the shim I have:

```
"jqGridz": ["jqueryUi", "jqGrid_i18n_en"]
```

Sometimes the end result is correctly resolved to:

```
/public/javascripts/jquery.jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js
```

But other times (a lot of times) it gets rendered as:

```
/public/javascripts/jqGridz.js
```

So instead of the path for jqGrid I'm getting the ID of the path.

This only happens on IE and I don't know why.

I'm using RequireJS v2.0.6

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out...
I picked up this project with RequireJS already implemented but it's a mess.

So what's happening is that whenever RequireJS can't load the resource (for me was a 404) it put the key name instead of the file path.

So basically if you have have this problem have a look at the resources loading list in Firebug or Fiddler and search for errors :)

Cheers!